# there is an error with laravel ( file_put_contents() failed to open stream: Permission denied )

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a problem with Laravel coding that I ran my project on cPanel. I encountered the error as shown below:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=maw4kz&s=9#.Wpb6ZHyYPIU][1]

```
file_put_contents(/Ik8QAmCPtQ3uAwA8CrWuXj5er6l4wkmonsFTirKy): failed to open stream: Permission denied
in Filesystem.php (line 122)
at HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_put_contents(/Ik8QAmCPtQ3uAwA8CrWuXj5er6l4wkmonsFTirKy): failed to open stream: Permission denied', '/home/webgraph/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php', 122, array('path' => '/Ik8QAmCPtQ3uAwA8CrWuXj5er6l4wkmonsFTirKy', 'contents' => 'a:3:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"95GMZ8vTLxeX4QlFh7gKXrD23xp8HtSGvBxn20i4";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:19:"http://webgraph.net";}s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}', 'lock' => true))
at file_put_contents('/Ik8QAmCPtQ3uAwA8CrWuXj5er6l4wkmonsFTirKy', 'a:3:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"95GMZ8vTLxeX4QlFh7gKXrD23xp8HtSGvBxn20i4";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:19:"http://webgraph.net";}s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}', 2)
in Filesystem.php (line 122)
at Filesystem->put('/Ik8QAmCPtQ3uAwA8CrWuXj5er6l4wkmonsFTirKy', 'a:3:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"95GMZ8vTLxeX4QlFh7gKXrD23xp8HtSGvBxn20i4";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:19:"http://webgraph.net";}s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}', true)
in FileSessionHandler.php (line 83)
at FileSessionHandler->write('Ik8QAmCPtQ3uAwA8CrWuXj5er6l4wkmonsFTirKy', 'a:3:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"95GMZ8vTLxeX4QlFh7gKXrD23xp8HtSGvBxn20i4";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:19:"http://webgraph.net";}s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}')
in Store.php (line 129)
at Store->save()
in StartSession.php (line 88)
at StartSession->terminate(object(Request), object(Response))
in Kernel.php (line 218)
at Kernel->terminateMiddleware(object(Request), object(Response))
in Kernel.php (line 189)
at Kernel->terminate(object(Request), object(Response))
in index.php (line 58)
```

I checked all permissions and I set all of my folder like storage and vendor to 777 permission on cpanel but unfortunately it didn't work and I searched about it a lot . I would be appreciated if someone guides me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use directory functions like `public_path() / app_path() / storage_path()` to save your files

[Documentaion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-app-path)

And if you have this error in first run , check your storage folder. you should have **app** and **framework** folders

Comment: I checked the path ,these directory functions have been set already, would you explain more? which part of file can I edit?

Comment: answer updated ... maybe you have some problem with folders ( for example cloning project from git without ignored folders ) @ElegUni